# Migrate Jboss AS 6 to WildFly 10 (UsersRolesLoginModule, CallerIdentityLoginModule, <security-domain>IG_CallerDS</security-domain>)?

Tags: migration, jboss6.x, wildfly-10

Please tell me how to migrate an application from the Jboss AS 6 in WildFly 10?
(sorry my english).

**target - the user must connect to the database using the username and password used in WildFly**

really want to read an example of realizing the possibilities of Jboss AS 6, if it is possible to implement in WildFly

**Configuration Jboss AS 6:**

```
<application-policy name = "IGRoles">
  <authentication>  
      <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule"  
        flag = "required">  
        <module-option name="usersProperties">IG_users.properties</module-option>  
        <module-option name="rolesProperties">IG_roles.properties</module-option>  
      </login-module>  
  </authentication>  
</application-policy> 

            <application-policy name = "IG_CallerDS">  
  <authentication>  
      <login-module code = "org.jboss.resource.security.CallerIdentityLoginModule"  
        flag = "required">  
        <module-option name = "managedConnectionFactoryName">jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=OraDSIG</module-option>  
      </login-module>  
  </authentication>  
</application-policy>

<datasources>  
  <local-tx-datasource>  
    <jndi-name>OraDSIG</jndi-name>  
<connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:olg1</connection-url>  
<driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>  
<security-domain>IG_CallerDS</security-domain>  
<exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>  
</local-tx-datasource>  
</datasources>
```

**Configuration WildFly 10:
test did the following:**
standalone.xml

```
       <security-domain name="ejb-security-domain33" cache-type="default">  
            <authentication>  
                <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">  
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>  
                </login-module>  
                <login-module code="UsersRoles" flag="required">  
                    <module-option name="defaultUsersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/ejb-users.properties"/>  
                    <module-option name="defaultRolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/ejb-roles.properties"/>  
                    <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/ejb-users.properties"/>  
                    <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/ejb-roles.properties"/>  
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>  
                </login-module>  
            </authentication>  
        </security-domain>
```

does not transmit the password but the file ejb-users.propertis requires

```
        <security-domain name="ejb-security-domain" cache-type="default">  
            <authentication>  
                <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">  
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>  
                </login-module>  
                <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">  
                    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>  
                </login-module>  
                <login-module code="DatabaseUsers" flag="required">  
                    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/OraDSIG"/>  
                    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select passwd AS PASSWORD from IG.USERS where login=?"/>  
                    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select role 'Roles', RoleGroup from IG.USER_ROLES where login=?"/>  
                </login-module>  
            </authentication>  
        </security-domain>
```

I checked a lot of variants, but the error is always this:

```
2016-12-01 10:46:14,472 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00236: Begin initialize method
2016-12-01 10:46:14,472 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00240: Begin login method
2016-12-01 10:46:14,472 DEBUG [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.AbstractServerLoginModule] (default task-2) Storing username 'ejbUser'
2016-12-01 10:46:14,472 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00236: Begin initialize method
2016-12-01 10:46:14,472 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00240: Begin login method
2016-12-01 10:46:14,473 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00236: Begin initialize method
2016-12-01 10:46:14,473 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00262: Module options [dsJndiName: java:jboss/OraDSIG, principalsQuery: select passwd AS PASSWORD from IG.USERS where login=?, rolesQuery: select role 'Roles', RoleGroup from IG.USER_ROLES where login=?, suspendResume: true]
2016-12-01 10:46:14,474 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00240: Begin login method
2016-12-01 10:46:15,283 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00263: Executing query select passwd AS PASSWORD from IG.USERS where login=? with username ejbUser
2016-12-01 10:46:15,618 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00283: Bad password for username ejbUser
2016-12-01 10:46:15,619 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00244: Begin abort method, overall result: true
2016-12-01 10:46:15,619 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00244: Begin abort method, overall result: true
2016-12-01 10:46:15,619 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00244: Begin abort method, overall result: false
2016-12-01 10:46:15,619 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-2) PBOX00206: Login failure: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: PBOX00070: Password invalid/Password required



                <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/OraDSIG" pool-name="OraDSIG" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">  
 <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:olg1</connection-url>  
 <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>  
 <driver>oracle</driver>  
                    <security>  
                          <user-name>ig</user-name>  
                        <password>abcd</password>  
                    </security>  
                    <validation>  
 <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>  
 <background-validation>true</background-validation>  
 <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>  
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>  
                    </validation>  
                </datasource>  

<driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle.jdbc">  
 <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver-class>  
</driver>
```

**Client WildFly 10**

```
CallerRemote remote=IGGetEJB.getEJBAccess3("ejbUser","1","127.0.0.1","8080"); 

  public static CallerRemote getEJBAccess3(String uName, String uPass,String serverHost, String serverPort) {  


     String serverUrl = "http-remoting://" + serverHost + ":" + serverPort; // serverPort обычно 4447  
     Hashtable<String, Object> params = new Hashtable<String, Object>();  
     params.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, serverUrl);  
     params.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");  
     params.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");   
     params.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "true");   
//    params.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, uName);  //java.naming.security.principal  
//    params.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, uPass);//java.naming.security.credentials  


     Properties clientProp = new Properties();  
     clientProp.put("remote.connections", "default");  
     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.host", serverHost);  
     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.port", serverPort);  
     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.username", uName);  
//    clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.password",uPass);  

    /* try { 
  MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256"); 
  byte[] passwordBytes = uPass.getBytes(); 
  byte[] hash = md.digest(passwordBytes); 
  String passwordHash = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hash); 
  System.out.println("password hash: "+passwordHash);     
  clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.password", "a4ayc/80/OGda4BO/1o/V0etpOqiLx1JwB5S3beHW0s="); 
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) { 
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
  e1.printStackTrace(); 
  }*/  


     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "true");  
//    clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS","JBOSS-LOCAL-USER");  
     clientProp.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "true");  

     EJBClientConfiguration cc = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(clientProp);  
     ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> selector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(cc);  
     EJBClientContext.setSelector(selector);  
//    EJBClientContext.getCurrent().registerInterceptor(0, new ClientInterceptor());  

     try {  
  InitialContext context = new InitialContext(params);    

  final String jndiName = "/TestRemoteEJBEAR/CallerBean!remote.CallerRemote";  
  CallerRemote remote = (CallerRemote) context.lookup(jndiName);  
// CallerRemote remote = connectEjb(context, jndiName);  
  return remote;  
  } catch (NamingException e) {  
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
  e.printStackTrace();  
  }  
  return null;  
  }
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

I changed - public abstract class UsernamePasswordLoginModule extends AbstractServerLoginModule

```
   public boolean login() throws LoginException
   {
   System.out.println("1______________super.login()="+super.login());
      // See if shared credentials exist
      if( super.login() == true )
      {
```

to receive a password from the client, should work **if( super.login() == true )**, but he always false

```
2016-12-05 15:26:21,640 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-10) PBOX00240: Begin login method
2016-12-05 15:26:21,641 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) 1______________super.login()=false
2016-12-05 15:26:21,641 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-10) PBOX00240: Begin login method
```

if( super.login() == false ) then password always = password=org.jboss.as.security.remoting.RemotingConnectionCredential@b986e1 and not equal password from DataBase

```
2016-12-05 15:26:22,080 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) 11______________expectedPassword=Pass_BD
2016-12-05 15:26:22,081 INFO  [stdout] (default task-10) 12______________password=org.jboss.as.security.remoting.RemotingConnectionCredential@b986e1



      super.loginOk = false;
      String[] info = getUsernameAndPassword();
...
   protected String[] getUsernameAndPassword() throws LoginException
   {
      String[] info = {null, null};
      // prompt for a username and password
      if( callbackHandler == null )
      {
         throw PicketBoxMessages.MESSAGES.noCallbackHandlerAvailable();
      }

      NameCallback nc = new NameCallback(PicketBoxMessages.MESSAGES.enterUsernameMessage(), "guest");
      PasswordCallback pc = new PasswordCallback(PicketBoxMessages.MESSAGES.enterPasswordMessage(), false);
```

I like the client to transfer your password?
as I call login() from the EJB client?

Tell me please.

Comment: Good day!
My EJB authenticates to the database using the user name and password.
Username and password entered in the Java client.
Please tell me, how do I pass the password from the client to the EJB Java. Using WildFly.

Or is there only option is to pass in the EJB parameters?

Answer (score 0):

remoute Java client works with this code

```
    public static CallerRemote getEJBAccessOK(String uName, String uPass,String serverHost, String serverPort) {  


     String serverUrl = "http-remoting://" + serverHost + ":" + serverPort; // serverPort обычно 4447  

     Hashtable<String, Object> params = new Hashtable<String, Object>();  
     params.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, serverUrl);  
     params.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");  
     params.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");   
     params.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");   
     params.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, uName);   
     params.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, uPass);  


     Properties clientProp = new Properties();  
     clientProp.put("remote.connections", "default");  
     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.host", serverHost);  
     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.port", serverPort);  
     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.username", uName);  
     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.password",uPass);  
     clientProp.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");  

     EJBClientConfiguration cc = new PropertiesBasedEJBClientConfiguration(clientProp);  
     ContextSelector<EJBClientContext> selector = new ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector(cc);  
     EJBClientContext.setSelector(selector);  
     try {  
  InitialContext context = new InitialContext(params);    
  final String jndiName = "/TestRemoteEJBEAR/CallerBean!remote.CallerRemote";  
  CallerRemote remote = (CallerRemote) context.lookup(jndiName);  
  return remote;  
  } catch (NamingException e) {  
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
  e.printStackTrace();  
  }  
  return null;  
}
```

CREATE TABLE "IG"."USER_ROLES"
  (    "LOGIN" VARCHAR2(64 BYTE),
    "ROLE" VARCHAR2(32 BYTE),
    "ROLEGROUP" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE)
  )
Insert into USER_ROLES (LOGIN,ROLE,ROLEGROUP) values ('ejbUser','ejbRole','Roles');

Comment: Can you please write a bit more what does the trick? What is the key Point of your answer? And what is that SQL code at the end of the questino?